# Calculate the maximum likelihood estimator, $\tilde{p}_{ML}$, of $p$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, likelihood

This problem was part of an assignment in my undergrad stats class.
Suppose Steph Curry takes ten 3-point shots per game, and the number of 3-point
shots scored follows a $\sim(10, )$ distribution, where  is the probability of successfully
scoring a 3-point shot. [Note: in basketball a 3-point shot is one taken from behind the 3-
point arc]. To estimate this probability, a random sample of 10 games is considered and
the number of successful 3-point shots is recorded. These data are shown below.

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\hline
5 & 3 & 0 & 7 & 10 \\
2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Calculate the maximum likelihood estimate, $\tilde{p}_{ML}$, of $p$, the probability of scoring a 3-
point shot, and verify (using either the first or second derivative test) that you have found
a maximum.

So I've $X\sim BIN(10,p)$

I go through the steps to find the estimator and arrive at

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i(1-p)=p\sum_{i=1}^{10}(10-x_i)
\end{equation}

I'm at a standstill in how I solve for $p$. Then when I have the estimator, do I do anything with the provided info in the table? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start by bringing the $1-p$ term outside the sum,
   $$ (1-p)\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i = p\sum_{i=1}^{10}(10-x_i)$$

Upon using the distributive property on $(1-p)\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i$, you will see that both sides of the equation have a $-p\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i$ that can cancel out.  You should be able to solve for $p$ from there.  You  may also need to know that $\sum_{i=1}^{a}b = a*b$, where $a$ is a fixed positive integer and $b$ is a fixed arbitrary real number.

2. Don't forget to apply the second derivative test to show that the critical point is a maximum.

3.To compute the MLE estimate: When you solve for $p$, you will get a formula for $\tilde{p}_{ML}$.  The numbers in the table correspond to the values of $x_i$ in that table.  Plug them in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I ended up getting $\tilde{p}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i}{10}$. Does this seem right? When I plug in the $x_i$'s I get 4.6. Is this the amount of 3's we expect him to make per game?

Comment: Close but no cigar.  $p$ is a probability, it should be between 0 and 1.  Hence, we would hope $\tilde{p}$ is also between 0 and 1.  You are missing a multiplicative factor.  Double check your algebra.

Comment: when I distribute the sum on the right hand side does the $10$ become $10\cdot 10$ which would give me $100$ in the denominator. I think you point this out above. But I overlooked it until now. thank you